# Pythagoras tree optimization?

Tags: java

This is my [Pythagorean tree attempt](http://pastebin.com/J2ERznmi). I am using a library with 3 main functions :

```
turnLeft(double angle)
turnRight(double angle)
drawLine(double length)
```

The original point of the pen is `(0,0)` and is facing right `( 0 degrees to X axis)`.

After hours of decoding and working on it I managed to make it work ( although not perfectly ) for angle 30 degrees in radians. But if I change my input to another value it just falls apart. I have been busting my head for the last couple of days on trying to improve this. Any advice on how could I handle this? Any advice on improving my algorithm?

Although you can't see really well, I marked in the image below the angle which is given as input. Thank you for any help. I know people frown upon these kind of questions but I am just starting to become hopeless. Have a nice day

[image: Geometric objects image]

Comment: That code in the paste bin is not complete ...

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/5e4dhe783/image1.png  
 http://s14.postimg.org/3qykp48q9/image2.png
 http://s23.postimg.org/w9ntlqksr/image3.png  The code is complete. What makes you say it isn't ? The name of the library is not shown but replaced with XX and the imports are not shown.

Comment: It is very hard to debug this type of problem without being able to see the output... More so because it may be a ui problem.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/libui   http://pastebin.com/fCFG8G6N  The library and the code. I am honestly not sure what to think. I don't think its a library problem since the library is given by my university. I appreciate any help. Just some pointers would be nice where you think I could work.